# INSERT INTO .. SELECT causing possible race condition?

Tags: postgresql

```
INSERT INTO A
SELECT * FROM B WHERE timestamp > (SELECT max(timestamp) FROM A);
```

or, written differently:

```
WITH selection AS
    (SELECT * FROM B WHERE timestamp > (SELECT max(timestamp) FROM A))
INSERT INTO A SELECT * FROM selection;
```

If these queries run multiple times simultaneously, is it possible that I will end up with duplicated rows in A?

How does Postgres process these queries? Is it one or multiple?

If it is multiple queries (find max(timestamp)[1], select[2] then insert[3]) I can imagine this will cause duplicated rows.

If that is correct, would wrapping it in BEGIN/END (a transaction) help?

Comment: Yes, that may result in duplicate values. The only way that is safe against concurrent execution is to define the `timestamp` column as a unique key, then use `insert ... on conflict`

Comment: Thx. Even wrapping it in BEGIN/END would cause it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that might result in duplicate values.

A single statement sees a consistent view of the data in all tables as of the point in time *when the statement started*.

Wrapping that single statement into a transaction won't change that (a single statement is always executed as an atomic statement regardless of the number of sub-query involved).

The statement will never see uncommitted data from other transactions (which is the root cause why you can wind up with duplicate values).

The **only** safe way to avoid duplicate values, is to create a unique constraint (or index) on that column. In that case the INSERT would result in an error if such a value already exists.

If you want to avoid the error, use `insert ... on conflict`

Comment: I don’t understand the “wrapping” paragraph.

Comment: @kev: sorry, I reworded that paragraph and forgot to delete the old text

Comment: I think there are still some words missing, but I think I understand now :-) Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: In regards to @Aditya's answer, even with Serializable (which we have set in Redshift) this would be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the isolation level set in your database.
This is from the [postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html)

By default, this is set to **Repeatable read**, which means that each query will get the output based on when the transaction first attempted to read the data. If 2 queries read before any one writes, then you will get duplicate data in these tables.

If you want to avoid having duplicate entries, you have a few options.

1. Try using the isolation level **Serializable**
2. Apply a unique index on a field of A in table B. Timestamp is not a great contender as you might legitimately have 2 rows with the same timestamp. Probably id of the table A is a good option.
3. Take a lock at the application level before performing such a query.

Comment: No, it does not depend on the isolation level (and the default level in Postgres is read committed). Even with read committed, this can lead to duplicate values.

Comment: At any level less than serializable, you will have issues. Added clarification